# Tags [proxy] and [proxies]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have the tags [proxy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proxy) (26) and [proxies](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proxies) (12). One question has both tags.

They should probably be synonymized. I’d prefer to keep [proxy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proxy).

Opinions?

Comment: Good catch, +1. Do we tend to plurals or singulars with the tags in general? Raw check: library, api, framework, game, calendar. But: graphs, web-services, maps, charts. Not that clear, though I tend to agree on `proxy` as the target. Let's hear some more opinions before starting on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synonym isn't necessary here; I just renamed `proxies` to `proxy` — DONE.

Synonyms were intended to link two completely separate words meaning essentially the same thing (think 'car' vs 'auto'). For simple variations on the *same* word, text completion will help guide the user to the correct usage.

<kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> → <kbd>proxy</kbd>

There's no need to bulk up the tag listings with every word inflection.